# ¿Como guardar la información de una fila que se va a eliminar en otra tabla con Trigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo la `tablau`:

```
Nombre  ApellidoP  ApellidoM
Juan    Ruiz       Robles
Pedro   Lopez      Lopez
Luis    Diaz       Ruiz
```

Y la tabla `log_users`

```
id     fecha_delete  Nombre
null   null          null
```

Además tengo el siguiente `Trigger`:

```
       CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER PRUEBA_BD_TRIGGER

            BEFORE DELETE ON test.tablau 
            FOR EACH ROW 
            BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO test.log_users 
             (fecha_delete,Nombre) VALUES (now(),Nombre); 

        END
```

Elimino registros de la `tablau` así:

```
delete FROM test.tablau where Nombre = 'Luis';
```

El trigger realiza lo siguiente en la tabla `log_users`:

```
id     fecha_delete           Nombre
1      2017-01-11 14:49:13
```

Como podrán observar no guarda el campo `Nombre` de la fila eliminada, como puedo hacer eso en el Trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza algo parecido a esto:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER PRUEBA_BD_TRIGGER  
    BEFORE DELETE ON test.tablau 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO test.log_users (fecha_delete,Nombre) VALUES (now(),OLD.Nombre); 
END
```

Con `OLD` se indica el valor antiguo de la columna. Para más información la documentación oficial de *Trigger* en **MySQL**:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Muchas gracias tienes toda la razón, funciona perfecto, creo que mi problema fue no investigar en la documentación oficial